# SELECT Statement Using CheckedListBox Values

Tags: c#, sql

I need to populate a second CheckedListBox with the results of a query whose values are dependent upon which options are checked in the initial CheckedListBox, re-Querying every time another box is checked or unchecked.

Additionally helpful would be a way to re-use the SqlConnection I'm utilizing. It seems to be a simple thing, but I can't figure out how to do it. Right now I've got this.

```
    private void Connection()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Project;Integrated Security=True");
        conn.Open();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter
        ("SELECT [StandardCode], c.CanStatement, [StandardDetail] FROM [dbo].[StandardCodesAndDetails] s JOIN dbo.CanStatements c ON c.StandardsID=s.ID", conn);
        adapter.Fill(ds);
        this.lstBoxStandardCodes.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        this.lstBoxStandardCodes.DisplayMember = "StandardCode";
        //conn.Close();
    }
```

On Initialization, it populates the first CheckedListBox (lstBoxStandardCodes), and I'm looking for a way to adjust those last two lines to accept variable input, to use it toward my first issue, if that makes sense. lstBoxStandardCodes would be changed to lstBoxStandardDetails (in this case), and "StandardCode" would become "StandardDetails". That last bit seems easy enough by changing `private void Connection()` to `private void Connection(string Member)` or such, but the rest isn't quite clicking for me.

If any further clarification is needed, please let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, I tested this locally, and it works fine.

```
    private void Connection()
    {
        //Please use a using statement as below
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=PWALTON-ACER;Initial Catalog=pwalton-test;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            conn.Open();

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter
            ("SELECT [StandardCode], c.CanStatement, [StandardDetail] FROM [dbo].[StandardCodesAndDetails] s JOIN dbo.CanStatements c ON c.StandardsID=s.ID", conn);
            adapter.Fill(ds);
            lstBoxStandardCodes.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            lstBoxStandardCodes.DataTextField = "StandardCode";
            lstBoxStandardCodes.DataBind(); //Don't forget to DataBind()

            lstBoxStandardDetails.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            lstBoxStandardDetails.DataTextField = "StandardDetail";
            lstBoxStandardDetails.DataBind(); //This list won't populate if you don't DataBind()
        }
    }
```

There wasn't any info included about the backing tables, but I deduced that it was probably something like this (based on the inline SQL in the original post): [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8c2cc/1)

Comment: With this, will clicking different or multiple selections from the StandardCode CheckedListBox alter the contents of the StandardDetail CheckedListBox every time?

Comment: @Eiketsu I think more info is needed. *How* will the selection in the first list affect the second? Also, do you expect things to happen asynchronously, or do you expect a page load to happen between when someone changes the first list and sees the change in the second one?

Comment: Right. I figured more information would be needed. Sorry about that. Basically, each Standard Code selected will list its related Standard Descriptions in the second box. Unchecking any will remove their Descriptions, and multiple Codes may be selected, resulting in multiple values listed in the Descriptions box. Each time something is checked or unchecked in the Codes box, the Descriptions box will change. Does that make more sense?

Comment: A little more. Can you give an example of how you want the SQL statement to change based on the selected info. Also, check the SQL Fiddle I posted in the answer to see if my assumptions about your backing tables were correct. If they were not, please modify it, and post a link to the modified version in a comment.

Comment: The only difference in the table would be that the CanStatement has a Foreign Key Constraint tied to the Standard Detail, if that matters. I would like to be able to be able to change the last three lines of the connection statement (the `DataSource`, `DataTextField`, and `DataBind` details). Setting the Standard Codes will be done at Initialization and unchanging; the Standard Details will update each time a new value in Codes is checked or unchecked, calling the Connection Method with the lstBoxStandardDetails values.

Comment: So let's say there is a `StandardCode` record with the values: [ID] 1, [StandardCode] 'Code1', [StandardDetail] 'Detail1'. When someone selects 'Code1' from the `lstBoxStandardCodes` list, what happens? Try thinking about how to change the query in order to get the desired results into `lstBoxStandardDetails`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76313/discussion-between-phil-walton-and-eiketsu).